# How to use JQUERY to call random forms

Tags: jquery, html

I was wondering if someone could provide some insight to as why when I click on the random form link below it doesn't randomly load one of the listed forms.  It works on jfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tUMBp/1/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- This calls the jquery library -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#randomForm').click(function() {
        var forms = $('#forms > form');
        forms.hide();
        forms.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * forms.length)).show();
    });
});
</script>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="forms">
    <form style="display:none;">
        This is your training site1
    </form>
    <form style="display:none;"><!-- the second form -->
        This is your training site2
    </form>
    <form style="display:none;"><!-- the second form -->
        This is your training site3
    </form>

    <form style="display:none;"><!-- the second form -->
       This is your training site4
    </form>


</div>



<a href="#" id="randomForm">Show random form</a>​



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use the name forms as a variable. Its a predefined name of implementation-dependent JavaScript!

Use formsList or something of the like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your jquery code runs before any forms exist on the page. At that point, you cannot assign the click event to `#randomForm` (jQuery will try to, but since `#randomForm` does not exist yet, it will do nothing).

Use the document.ready handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#randomForm').click(function() {
        var forms = $('#forms > form');
        forms.hide();
        forms.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * forms.length)).show();
    });​
});​
</script>
```

Comment: I do see where I went wrong, but by changing it to a    $(document).ready(function(){       it still is not doing anything once the link is clicked.

Comment: Is the code you posted your full code? Can there be something else on the page causing an error? Did you check the js console?

Comment: I update the update full code.  I have tried it with firebug and this is the only error I get:  illegal character Line 14 which is });

Comment: You probably have some invisible character causing that. It may have come from a bad copy/paste. See if your editor has an option to show invisible characters, or just retype everything on a new file.

Answer (score 0):

**JQUERY UPDATE**

Put the jQuery code inside

> $(document).ready(function() { // code });

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#randomForm').click(function() {
        var forms = $('#forms > form');
        forms.hide();
        forms.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * forms.length)).show();
    });
});
```